# PHP sending POST request via curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I need to make a POST request to an external http API using curl. When I call the API using the curl command line, it returns the correct data. However, I'm struggling to get the right data when calling it from a php script.

When I use the curl command from the terminal, I get the correct data:

curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "type_category_id=4" http://example.com/api/

What is the correct format for the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS in my curl_setopts() in php?

I tried the following (and failed):

```
<?php
$data = "type_category_id=4";

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/api/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Comment: show us your php script

Comment: I've edited the question with the code.

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` and drop the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it `Accept: application/json` instead of `Content-Type: application/json`

You have done that in the command line but not in the php script.