# how to post php variables to other page using curl?

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I'm trying to use the twitter api to make a login to my website this is my first time using any api so its really confusing for me i have read a bit online searching how to make the OAuth and found a project on git-hub which allows us to connect but this will not help me to learn `php` so i tried the twitter documentation and found [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter). The diagram in that page shows that i should post the data to the twitter api urls again searched for on google and found a `stackoverflow` [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319477/php-sending-post-request-via-curl) but don't know how to use this is there any other tutorial or book that explains all of this? This is what i understood from reading the twitter documentation if im wrong please help me rectify my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have to first get a request token.
Try this method, it should work (not tested) :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$clientSecret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($yourPost));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Then follow the instruction of step 2 using CURL with GET