# Send Data From PHP CURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I need to send some form data (POST) to a URL.

But I do not wish my script go to her.

I have a list of users in the database, I need to spend http://www.somesite.com/receive

Except that my script can not go there.

It would be possible to make a POST request without leaving the page? (without using the Ajax).

Something like CURL?

Comment: You can use curl on the server side and ajax on the client side.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little hard to understand. If I had enough rep, I would ask clarification in a comment, but I can't.

Do you simply want to use curl to send an HTTP POST request? If so, you can use [PHP's curl functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), making sure to set CURLOPT_POST to true. This code is from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440252/php-curl-i-need-a-simple-post-request-and-retrival-of-page-example):

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://www.example.com/yourscript.php",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'field1' => 'some date',
        'field2' => 'some other data',
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// result sent by the remote server is in $result
```

Here are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319477/php-sending-post-request-via-curl) more [references](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post).